# memcache won't store key/value because the value is too big

Tags: python, django, memcached, key-value

```
cache.set(key, Biglist, 3600)
print cache.get(key)
```

When my "Biglist" is a huge list of lots of content, it doesn't seem to store.

But when I change it to small text like "abc", it stores.

What do I have to configure so that I can set my memcache to accept unlimited size of key/value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [What is the maximum data size you can store](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_data_size_you_can_store?_(1_megabyte)) section in the FAQ.

> **What is the maximum data size you can store? (1 megabyte)**
>
> The maximum size of a value you can store in memcached is 1 megabyte. If your data is larger, consider clientside compression or splitting the value up into multiple keys.
>
> **Why are items limited to 1 megabyte in size?**
>
> Ahh, this is a popular question!
>
> Short answer: Because of how the memory allocator's algorithm works.