# Django memcached won't cache a large template output

Tags: django, memcached

I am using Django with memcached.

In one of my templates, I added

```
{% cache 28800 template_browse_gene_list %}
...
{% endcache %}
```

The stuff in the block is rather large, just over 1 MB; it is the result of iterating through an expensive SQL that returns lots of data. Since QuerySet is lazily evaluated, using the cache here avoids the SQL, if cache works.

When I use locmem as the cache backend, this works. I avoid the SQL and get cached result.

When I hookup memcached, with -I 4m setting, I get the following in the verbose output:

```
<30 new auto-negotiating client connection
30: Client using the ascii protocol
....
<30 get template.cache.template_browse_gene_list.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
>30 END
<30 connection closed.
```

The connection closed line is displayed as soon as the page is returned, but after quite a wait. I think basically when the SQL is done, the connection closed message appears. So basically, nothing gets into memcached for this entry. Again, this worked with locmem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this... explains it...

[memcache won't store key/value because the value is too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917484/memcache-wont-store-key-value-because-the-value-is-too-big)